How to install prerequisite during installation
I have already created an installer for my application using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Installer Project. The installer installs my application and automatically launches the setup for any missing prerequisite programs. For example, if the user's computer doesn't have the required version of the .NET 8 runtime, the installer will automatically run the setup for that version. If the prerequisites are already installed, the installer won't execute their setups.
I am exploring the Launch Conditions feature to ensure everything works as expected, but I haven't found a comprehensive solution on how to achieve this. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!
